# Interface contract for struct tm and mktime() regarding time zone conversions

Tags: c, mktime

While running the following C code, I noticed that mktime() apparently does some time zone conversions when called.

```
void process_time(struct tm * pt) {
    printf("pt %02d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", pt->tm_year, pt->tm_mon, pt->tm_mday,
            pt->tm_hour, pt->tm_min, pt->tm_sec);

    ret = mktime(pt);

    printf("pt %02d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", pt->tm_year, pt->tm_mon, pt->tm_mday,
            pt->tm_hour, pt->tm_min, pt->tm_sec);

    /* more code here */
}
```

In some cases (which turned out to be due to some `struct tm` members not being properly initialized), I noticed that after the call to `mktime()`, `pt->tm_hour` was one less than it was before. Local system time is an hour east of UTC, so that corresponds to a local-to-UTC conversion.

According to [this source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/), `struct tm` should merely have the usual YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss fields, in addition to weekday, day of the year and a DST flag—no mention of the time zone or UTC offset.

However, when I examine the struct on Ubuntu (`/usr/include/time.h`), I notice two extra fields for UTC offset and a time zone string.

What is the interface contract for `struct tm`? Does it mandate these time zone conversions, and if so, how are `struct tm` members supposed to be interpreted regarding time zones after `mktime()` has normalized them?

Comment: I would not expect `tm_hour` to change value, *unless* it or `tm_min` or `tm_sec` were nonnormalized, or if `tm_isdst` was passed in as 0 or 1, and was mismatched with the actual dst status of the time being converted.  In general, you should set `tm_isdst` to -1 before calling `mktime`.  Does this help?  How were you passing `tm_isdst`?

Comment: For much more information on best practices for time programming, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices) and [this web page](http://www.catb.org/esr/time-programming/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the interface contract for `struct tm`?

The key parts of `mktime()` specification is:

> The mktime function converts the broken-down time, expressed as **local time** ... The original values of the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` components of the structure are ignored, and the original values of the other components are not restricted to the ranges indicated above. ... On successful
>   completion, ...  components are set to represent the specified calendar
>   time, but with their values forced to the ranges indicated above.
>   C11dr §7.27.2.3 2

The values of `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` are ignored.  Members specifying the year, month, day, hour, minute, second **and** the `.isdst` contribute, but other   platform specified ones can affect the result.  This could include nanosecond, timezone, UTC offset, etc. members.

Robust code sets all members.

```
struct tm t = {0};        // clear **all** members
t.tm_year = 2018 - 1900;  // Assign some members
t.tm_mon = 2 - 1;
t.tm_mday = 1; // today
t.tm_isdst = -1;          // Let system determine if DST applies for this date
process_time(&t);
```

---

> I noticed that after the call to mktime(), pt->tm_hour was one less than it was before.

This is likely due to `.tm_isdst < 0`.

> The value of `tm_isdst` is positive if Daylight Saving Time is in effect, zero if Daylight Saving Time is not in effect, and negative if the information is not available. §7.27.1 4
>   Footnote 320: A negative value causes it to attempt to determine whether Daylight Saving Time is in effect for the specified time.

Add `.tm_isdst` to 2 lines in `process_time()` to see the effect.

```
 printf("pt %02d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d  %d\n", 
     pt->tm_year, pt->tm_mon, pt->tm_mday, 
     pt->tm_hour, pt->tm_min, pt->tm_sec, pt->tm_isdst);
```

---

> how are `struct tm` members supposed to be interpreted regarding time zones after `mktime()` has normalized them?

As normalized local time.

Comment: Note: After `mktime(t)`, `t->tm_isdst` may have changed from its original setting to reflect §7.27.1 4

Answer (score 1):

chux answered most of this.  Here's a bit more info.

You asked about `tm_gmtoff` and `tm_zone`.  These are nonstandard additions to `struct tm`, although they're both very useful and very common.  They are ignored on input to `mktime`, but set on output.  They probably have nothing to do with the unusual result you saw.

Comment: `tm_gmtoff and tm_zone` [...] both very useful and very common` indeed, though it makes me wonder why the original authors never thought about including timezone information in `struct tm`, or about a `mktime()` variant capable of processing UTC timestamps…

Comment: @user149408 As you may know, the third thing that's both very useful and very common, though nonstandard, is `timegm`, the `mktime` variant for UTC timestamps.  These things were left out originally, I think, because it took a while for the C/Unix community to really figure out how to handle time zones well.  The need for the `tm_zone` and `tm_gmtoff` members, and the inadequacy of the mechanisms that preceded them, took a while to be realized.

Comment: @SteveSummit Concerning  `tm_gmtoff, tm_zone` members being very common: Aside from glibc compliant libraries, Any examples of a library having these in `struct tm`?  I have not noticed these as common - especially in embedded compilers.

Comment: @chux Besides glibc, I believe they're present in BSD and MacOS and many (though probably not all) "mainframe" Unix editions (Solaris, etc.).  But I wouldn't argue with an impression that they're not common in the embedded world.

Comment: Solaris might [not](https://github.com/oetiker/rrdtool-1.x/issues/330) have `tm_gmtoff` and MS does not appear to have it either.  IMO, a missing `mktime_UTC()` is a hole in the Standard C library.